NRE без ссылки на объект
Unity начал выдавать ошибку (которая не мешает компиляции кода), кто-нибудь знает что это? Нажатие на ошибку ничего не дает кроме открытия Graph
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEditor.Graphs.Edge.WakeUp () (at <d38a7573bc684cda95a248e6e5884edc>:0)
UnityEditor.Graphs.Graph.DoWakeUpEdges (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] inEdges, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] ok, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] error, System.Boolean inEdgesUsedToBeValid) (at <d38a7573bc684cda95a248e6e5884edc>:0)
UnityEditor.Graphs.Graph.WakeUpEdges (System.Boolean clearSlotEdges) (at <d38a7573bc684cda95a248e6e5884edc>:0)
UnityEditor.Graphs.Graph.WakeUp (System.Boolean force) (at <d38a7573bc684cda95a248e6e5884edc>:0)
UnityEditor.Graphs.Graph.WakeUp () (at <d38a7573bc684cda95a248e6e5884edc>:0)
UnityEditor.Graphs.Graph.OnEnable () (at <d38a7573bc684cda95a248e6e5884edc>:0)


Ну так исправь её...

Я не понимаю на какой объект/скрипт ссылается ошибка, как я ее исправлю?

Ранее попадались NRE, но они ссылались на строку или строки кода, а здесь ссылка неизвестно на что

Я так понимаю, какой-то компонент валится, когда его пытаются показать в дизайнере? Или я неправ?

В том-то и дело, что я просто запускаю код. После перезапуска ошибка (пока что) исчезла. Не понимаю что это было.
